# Subversion security issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In SVN i have one folder testing

```
/testing
```

and three sub-folder

```
/testing
  /t1
  /t2
  /t3
```

I initially assigned read-write permission on `testing` and all the three sub-folders. On check out of `testing` I can see `t1`, `t2`, `t3` folders on my local machine as expected.

I remove `t2` folder from my machine and then removed read-write permission for `t2` svn folder only. On update of `testing` I still see `t2` folder inside `testing` contrary to my expectation.

On fresh checkout of testing, i however doesn't see `t2` folder inside `testing`.

How to ensure that on update too i don't see `t2` folder after removal of permission ?

Comment: @Ken White - thank you for the edit.

Comment: What server are you using?  Are you controlling permission via Active directory groups, or the path based permissions using a config file

Comment: @RobGoodwin I am using path based permission. Details here http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html